# Como limpiar unos textbox convertidos a Double

Tags: c#

Tengo esta evento del `textbox` **cantidadvendida**:

```
private void txtcantidadvendida_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            double existencia, venta;
            existencia = Convert.ToDouble(txtexistencia.Text);
            venta = Convert.ToDouble(txtcantidadvendida.Text);

            if (venta > existencia)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La cantidad que quiere vender es mayor que la cantidad disponible actualmente para la venta de este producto.");
                txtcodigo.Clear();
                txtdescripcion.Clear();
                txtreferencia.Clear();
                txtmarca.Clear();
                txtexistencia.Clear();
                txtcantidadvendida.Clear();
                txtpreciopieza.Clear();
                txttotalventa.Clear();
                txtcodigo.Enabled = false;
                btnbuscar.Enabled = false;
                txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = false;
                btnañadir.Enabled = false;
                btneliminar.Enabled = false;
                btnventa.Enabled = false;
                txtcodigo.Enabled = true;
                btnbuscar.Enabled = true;
                txtcodigo.Select();
            }
            else
            {
                Double a = 0;
                a = Double.Parse(txtcantidadvendida.Text) * Double.Parse(txtpreciopieza.Text);
                txttotalventa.Text = a.ToString();
                txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

Y un botón limpiar:

```
private void btnlimpiar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            txtcedula.Enabled = true;
            txtcedula.Clear();
            txtcedula.Select();
            btnbuscar2.Enabled = true;
            txtnombre.Clear();
            txtapellido.Clear();
            txttelefono.Clear();
            txtcelular.Clear();
            txtcodigo.Clear();
            txtdescripcion.Clear();
            txtreferencia.Clear();
            txtmarca.Clear();
            txtexistencia.Clear();
            txtcantidadvendida.Clear();
            txtpreciopieza.Clear();
            txttotalventa.Clear();
            txtcodigo.Enabled = false;
            btnbuscar.Enabled = false;
            txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = false;
            btnañadir.Enabled = false;
            btneliminar.Enabled = false;
            btnventa.Enabled = false;
            txtcedula.Select();
        }
```

Si tengo ya mis `textbox` del formulario llenos, pero cometí un error y quiero limpiarlos, cuando doy click en el botón me da el siguiente error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

Y me señala el error en esta parte de la conversión:

```
double existencia, venta;'

existencia = Convert.ToDouble(txtexistencia.Text);

venta = Convert.ToDouble(txtcantidadvendida.Text);
```

Comment: Creía que el método `Convert.ToDouble` permitía Nulls o cadenas, pero no es así, por lo que dice la documentación (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx) . Sería muy buena idea entonces que parsees como indica la respuesta de @Katz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de realizar la función "Convert.ToDouble":

```
double existencia, venta;'

existencia = Convert.ToDouble(txtexistencia.Text);

venta = Convert.ToDouble(txtcantidadvendida.Text);
```

Necesitas verificar que los textbox en su propiedad Text tengan valor, esto lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtexistencia.Text))
            {

                //Se crea una veriable auxiliar ya que el metodo TryParse requiere un 
                //parametro de tipo double y que sea definido como salida
                double parseAux = 0.0;

                //Aqui es donde trata de parsear el valor que hay en el textbox
                double.TryParse(txtexistencia.Text, out parseAux);

            }
```

ademas utiliza la función double.TryParse para verificar que el valor en la propiedad Text del textbox se pueda parsear.

Comment: gracias muchas gracias me funciono a la perfeccion.